# How to measure the number of direct memory access(DMA) on a mobile phone?

Tags: android, mobile, dma, performance-measuring

I want to measure the number of memory access of cnn models, these models runs on NPU on a SoC chip.

I have few knowledge about DMAs and SoC architecture, and it's also hard for me to get a good keyword to Google.

So could anybody tell me how to measure the number of memory bytes accessed by DMA on mobile phone or give me some useful keyword or reading links to start with?

Comment: Given that Qualcomm has its own SDK using a DSP on SoC: [Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK](https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/overview.html) I'm not sure if looking for DMA speeds is meaningful.

Comment: I am using Huawei's Mate10 and its NPU, I observed a bottleneck of CNN, I think the bottleneck comes from memory access. And I need to collect evidence to confirm my  judgment.

Comment: Assuming you are using the Android Neural Network API: https://source.android.com/devices/interaction/neural-networks given that there isn't much detail on Mate 10's CPU: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/hisilicon/kirin/970